# How can I solve the problem of (Incompatible sender/receiver arguments)?

Tags: qt, qt4

Here is the code where I use `CONNECT`.I use it to go to the slot `slotReadyRead` where i can read the content the reply.
But I have a message while debugging or running the program which is

> QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
>           QNetworkReplyImpl::readyRead() --> MainWindow::slotReadyRead(QNetworkReply*)

**.cpp**

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
     QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
     QNetworkRequest request;
     request.setUrl(QUrl("http://lascivio.co/mobile/get.php?name=marwa"));
     QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
     connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead(QNetworkReply*)));
}
void MainWindow::slotReadyRead(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QByteArray b (reply->readAll());
    QString s(b);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(s);
}
```

**.h**

```
public slots:
    void slotReadyRead(QNetworkReply* reply);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slot needs to have a signature compatible with the signal. So either define it as:

```
void slotReadyRead();
```

Or make the reply optional:

```
void slotReadyRead(QNetworkReply* reply = null);
```

Comment: I changed it to --> "void slotReadyRead();" + defined the reply variable in .h file so i could access it though any function ... It finally works Thanks very much :)

Comment: I have 1 reputation and it's required 14 extra reputation to vote for good answers :)

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know about this limit.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force a plug into a socket, if it is not meant to be. I see two options:

1. Make `reply` a member of `MainWindow` (the quick and dirty solution)
2. Create a new class that will have a `QNetworkReply*` as a member and a slot to process the data of the reply, when it is ready.

BTW: I think you want to `connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(slotProcessReply())` ([documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qnetworkreply.html#finished)). [And here is the HTTP example from the Qt example collection](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/network-http.html)! Have a look at [network/http/httpwindow.h](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/network-http-httpwindow-h.html) and [network/http/httpwindow.cpp](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/network-http-httpwindow-cpp.html)

Comment: Thank you.It'll be considered :)